# Which methods need android.permission.DEVICE_POWER in Android?

Tags: android, permissions

I am looking at the AOSP clock application and it requires the `android.permission.DEVICE_POWER permission`. This permission is only granted to system apps so if I want to modify the clock, I can't publish it with that permission. I need to know which methods rely on `android.permission.DEVICE_POWER` in order for my new app not to crash. The android documentation doesn't seem to provide a good understanding of that permission and who needs it. I need to make sure it's safe to remove its usage.

Answer (score 2):

Device_Power provides methods such as goToSleep() which forces the device to sleep, usage of this may cause a security exception.

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
pm.reboot(null);
```

This will reboots the device, you need to have additional reboot permission and may be a rooted device as well.